# App´s won´t install even if I have the default writing location set to the SD Card

Tags: google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop, sd-card, gallery

I recently bought a phone with the horrible android 5.0 Lollipop. Now I regret I ever bought it. I have some major issues with the playstore and the gallery.

First of all I cannot download any app, I´ve got an SD card and have it set to be my defualt writing location, it has over 1 GB of free space left, all the big apps like facebook and whatsapp are on the SD card but it still will not let me download any app. Everytime I try download an app even if it is just
3MB in size.

Then the gallery.... I don´t know what they were thinking but they removed the almighty "move from album to album" function.... smart move..

Does anyone know how to fix these problems? otherwise I'm just going to downgrade to 4.0 which will feel like an upgrade in this case.

Comment: Sounds like you have a good plan! Just make sure you either: a) disable stagefright in your build.prop file, or b) use Textra as your default SMS messaging app, and you'll be just as secure as everyone else. (Btw, why 4.0 instead of 4.3 or 4.4? If you can find a 4.0 ROM I'd be surprised.)

Answer (score -2):

May be you need to update Google Play Services. You can do this through the Google Play Store.